# How to move a player in a fixed direction despite camera rotation in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx

I make a 2D game in LibGDX and the player movement system is pretty simple:

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W))
       player.setPosition(player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y + 100 * delta);
```

And the same principle for the A, S and D key.

But now, I have a "drunk mode" - hence, there is a camera rotation in the world, so just:

```
camera.rotate(MathUtils.random(-50, 50) * delta);
```

But if I press the W key when the camera rotates, the player doesn't move straight upwards anymore. So, if the rotation is e.g. 180°, the player moves straight downwards, which is actually pretty logical.

So is there a way that the player **always** moves, upwards when pressing W, rightwards when pressing D etc. no matter what's the current rotation?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use a vector (in your case that'd be [0, 100] and rotate it in the opposite direction, then move the player by that vector

Answer (score 0):

Try using the deviation on the player in the same direction.

```
final int PLAYER_SPEED = 100;
float angle = MathUtils.random(-50, 50) * delta; // btw, delta is Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()?
camera.rotate(angle);
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) {
    float xOffset = PLAYER_SPEED * sin(toRadians(angle)) * delta;
    float yOffset = PLAYER_SPEED * cos(toRadians(angle)) * delta;
    player.setPosition(player.getPosition().x + xOffset, player.getPosition().y + yOffset);
}
```

For other directions there must be other trigonometric formulas.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of 5tingr4y worked for me.

So, I just created a vector and rotated it in the opposite direction. Then, I move the player by that Vector.